# JAVA: Algorithms : How can i perform Subtraction Operation in Encrypted Values

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I have a code of Paillier homomorphic algorithm, In which the **multiplication** and **Addition** are performing in Encrypted values.

I need to implement **subtraction** and **division** (at least subtraction) in the same way of **Addition** is implemented (operation in Encrypted values),

I had tried, But did not get expected output,

Code is -

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Paillier {

/**
* p and q are two large primes. 
* lambda = lcm(p-1, q-1) = (p-1)*(q-1)/gcd(p-1, q-1).
*/
private BigInteger p, q, lambda;
/**
* n = p*q, where p and q are two large primes.
*/
public BigInteger n;
/**
* nsquare = n*n
*/
public BigInteger nsquare;
/**
* a random integer in Z*_{n^2} where gcd (L(g^lambda mod n^2), n) = 1.
*/
private BigInteger g;
/**
* number of bits of modulus
*/
private int bitLength;

/**
* Constructs an instance of the Paillier cryptosystem.
* @param bitLengthVal number of bits of modulus
* @param certainty The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 2^(-certainty)). The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter.
*/
public Paillier(int bitLengthVal, int certainty) {
KeyGeneration(bitLengthVal, certainty);
}

/**
* Constructs an instance of the Paillier cryptosystem with 512 bits of modulus and at least 1-2^(-64) certainty of primes generation.
*/
public Paillier() {
KeyGeneration(512, 64);
}

/**
* Sets up the public key and private key.
* @param bitLengthVal number of bits of modulus.
* @param certainty The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 2^(-certainty)). The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter.
*/
public void KeyGeneration(int bitLengthVal, int certainty) {
bitLength = bitLengthVal;
/*Constructs two randomly generated positive BigIntegers that are probably prime, with the specified bitLength and certainty.*/
p = new BigInteger(bitLength / 2, certainty, new Random());
q = new BigInteger(bitLength / 2, certainty, new Random());

n = p.multiply(q);
nsquare = n.multiply(n);

g = new BigInteger("2");
lambda = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).divide(
p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).gcd(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
/* check whether g is good.*/
if (g.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).gcd(n).intValue() != 1) {
System.out.println("g is not good. Choose g again.");
System.exit(1);
}
}

/**
* Encrypts plaintext m. ciphertext c = g^m * r^n mod n^2. This function explicitly requires random input r to help with encryption.
* @param m plaintext as a BigInteger
* @param r random plaintext to help with encryption
* @return ciphertext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Encryption(BigInteger m, BigInteger r) {
return g.modPow(m, nsquare).multiply(r.modPow(n, nsquare)).mod(nsquare);
}

/**
* Encrypts plaintext m. ciphertext c = g^m * r^n mod n^2. This function automatically generates random input r (to help with encryption).
* @param m plaintext as a BigInteger
* @return ciphertext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Encryption(BigInteger m) {
BigInteger r = new BigInteger(bitLength, new Random());
return g.modPow(m, nsquare).multiply(r.modPow(n, nsquare)).mod(nsquare);

}

/**
* Decrypts ciphertext c. plaintext m = L(c^lambda mod n^2) * u mod n, where u = (L(g^lambda mod n^2))^(-1) mod n.
* @param c ciphertext as a BigInteger
* @return plaintext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Decryption(BigInteger c) {
BigInteger u = g.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).modInverse(n);
return c.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).multiply(u).mod(n);
}

/**
* main function
* @param str intput string
*/
public static void main(String[] str) {
/* instantiating an object of Paillier cryptosystem*/
Paillier paillier = new Paillier();
/* instantiating two plaintext msgs*/
BigInteger m1 = new BigInteger("20");
BigInteger m2 = new BigInteger("60");
/* encryption*/
BigInteger em1 = paillier.Encryption(m1);
BigInteger em2 = paillier.Encryption(m2);
/* printout encrypted text*/
System.out.println("En Result1="+em1);
System.out.println("En Result2="+em2);
/* printout decrypted text */
System.out.println("Dec Result1="+paillier.Decryption(em1).toString());
System.out.println("Dec Result2="+paillier.Decryption(em2).toString());

/* test homomorphic properties -> D(E(m1)*E(m2) mod n^2) = (m1 + m2) mod n */
BigInteger product_em1em2 = em1.multiply(em2).mod(paillier.nsquare);
BigInteger sum_m1m2 = m1.add(m2).mod(paillier.n);
System.out.println("original sum: " + sum_m1m2.toString());
System.out.println("decrypted sum: " + paillier.Decryption(product_em1em2).toString());

/* test homomorphic properties -> D(E(m1)^m2 mod n^2) = (m1*m2) mod n */
BigInteger expo_em1m2 = em1.modPow(m2, paillier.nsquare);
BigInteger prod_m1m2 = m1.multiply(m2).mod(paillier.n);
System.out.println("original product: " + prod_m1m2.toString());
System.out.println("decrypted product: " +   paillier.Decryption(expo_em1m2).toString());
}
}
```

My try was like this

```
BigInteger sub_m1m2 = em1.subtract(em2).mod(paillier.nsquare);
System.out.println("original result: " + sub_m1m2.toString());
System.out.println("decrypted result: " +   paillier.Decryption(sub_m1m2).toString());
```

But i got output

```
original result: 10293905733728092798312442334016670915623579115754799359001594575265037444846358865955447355482410894470382250544497599054315984048041610855086875271446876264557306222798287261349828881510552405863659535527193007559975944762965701441522047569562634431616852659521060136138153805278432999456874447872696991987
decrypted result: 5329364443144332451351943891466568608903938067239264159825694002586308632766687575085696305071770727742308734013289113539866112418155659162072887614141015

Expected output
 -40
```

Give me at least the way to correct logic.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUBTRACTION IN ENCRYPTED VALUES

I got the partial answer with the logic **A +  (-B)**

Eg:-

```
BigInteger m1 = new BigInteger("200");
BigInteger m2 = new BigInteger("-100");

BigInteger em1 = paillier.Encryption(m1);
BigInteger em2 = paillier.Encryption(m2);

BigInteger product_em1em2 = em1.multiply(em2).mod(paillier.nsquare);
System.out.println("decrypted Result: " + paillier.Decryption(product_em1em2).toString());
```

Output you got

```
decrypted Result:100
```

The problem in the logic is if **B > A**, then you will get a wrong result like

```
8731467600700263693874424644022096065561525426062533141985672767376667419304955165494349828630814277855336552046469491700406386664031693931688991036643291
```

Answer (score 0):

[JS Paillier demo](http://mhe.github.io/jspaillier/)

Really sweet demo for Pallier cryptosystems using javascript.

I used this demo for subtraction as a type of addition - A + (-B) . This worked as long as |A| was larger than |B|. It gave me a seemingly encrypted number when |B| was larger.

Another [link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9697/is-it-possible-to-subtract-multiply-numbers-using-homomorphic-encryption) It didn't give a definite answer or algorithm though

Edit: [Paillier Division is possible under conditions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/division-in-paillier-cryptosystem)

Comment: Actually, i need to implement this in Android, So Javascript may not be a better solution, But i will try your logic..............And thankz for your help

Comment: I gave a link to the demo as way to test input and logic :)

Comment: I think your logic should be like this A+(-B),So you will get result. If both A and B are -ve the output should be  a encrypted number.   (Both cases A should be the larger number )   NB:-based on the code that i have posted above.

Answer (score 0):

This is modular arithmetic, the answer is actually correct mod n.  if you want the signed answer in this case you can get it by taking result-n if b > a.  Full example,

```
a=100, b=200
a-b = a + (-b)

public n: 189073144844662281547025573708278983341
private lambda: 94536572422331140759761643656524564142
[A] = 14186854275058373459357566990685202758595128512711002543934861918137101534797
[B] = 27267516796978636717778486386991056397778775888737369113501780748148589365346
[A + B] = 23137393292983120368330149560489233461976816700037321139211632742863926737409
res = 189073144844662281547025573708278983241
res - n = -100
```